# How do I multiply a complex number with a scalar quantity (non-complex number) in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, complex-numbers

I'm using Microsoft Excel to compute data for an analysis project in Electrical Engineering. I need to multiply a complex number with a non-complex/scalar number. But Excel keeps showing me "#VALUE!" error.

The complex number is in one cell, and the real/scalar/non-complex number is in another cell. I'm using formula to multiply the two numbers, and the result is placed in a third cell. The Error message keeps showing every time I compute.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a complex number with a zero imaginary part and use IMPRODUCT to multiply them:-

```
=IMPRODUCT(A1,COMPLEX(B1,0))
```

where A1 is complex and B1 is real.